# Access Bundle resources(fonts, images) from iOS objective-c framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

Created MyFramework.framework to share views I am displaying between my applications. Currently, I am using MyFramework in the application "MyApp".
Created bundle named **Resources.bundle** inside the framework(MyFrawork.framework) I use in my projects. 
I put some images and fonts there. I put this bundle in **Copy bundle Resources** inside MyFrawork.framework.
When trying to get a window from MyFramowork.framework, my fonts and images are not loaded...
What am I trying to do is:

```
    NSString *fontName;
    static NSBundle* frameworkBundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;

    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        NSString* mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        NSString* frameworkBundlePath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Resources.bundle"];
        frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];
    });
    NSLog(@"[Bundle] IS NULL: %@", frameworkBundle == nil ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    NSString *fontPath = [frameworkBundle pathForResource:@"Roboto-Regular" ofType:@"ttf"];
    NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fontPath];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)inData);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
    CFErrorRef error;
    fontName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CGFontCopyPostScriptName(font));
    if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
        NSLog(@"[FONT]Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
        CFRelease(errorDescription);
    }
```

frameworkBundle always nil, so I have in log "[Bundle] IS NULL: YES" always.
All the above is done in MyFrawork.framwork. And here how I am trying to load font I am using:

```
[title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:11]];
```

How can I access Resource.bundle from MyFramework.framework, so I can use those resources from other application?

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you would implement PureData via LibPD Framework and placed some basic PD-File (.pd) as a resource into the library to be loaded from the bundle.

```
┬─── YourApp Workspace
├┬── libpd.xcodeproj //LibPD Framework
│└┬─ PDBase.h
│ └─ SomeFile.pd
└┬── YourApp Source Folder
 ├── AppDelegate.h
 ├── ... other ...
```

you should be able to access the file with `bundleForClass:` if you have a *baseclass* that your Framework defines (well, it should have one)

```
NSBundle *pdBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[PdBase class]];
NSString *path=[pdBundle pathForResource:@"SomeFile" ofType:@"pd"];
```

(untested) PS: would be nice to see your structure in detail to help you out. And there are a lot other ways to reach the file.. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle) like..

`[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.organisation.projectname"]`

Comment: and what if I have UnityFramework.framework and this static library locates inside this dynamic library?

Comment: Unity Doc: *"UnityFramework Objective-C class, which is a principal class of UnityFramework.framework:"* `+ (UnityFramework*)getInstance;`